# Upgrading from OS X El Capitan to macOS High Sierra

Tags: homebrew, java

I'm in the process of planning an upgrade from OS X El Capitan to macOS High Sierra, and I'm using things like Homebrew, Composer, Elasticsearch, and — by extension — Java.

I'm using MAMP Pro with the files stored in: `/Library/WebServer/Documents/`.

I need to know if these things will remain intact after the upgrade, or whether I have to install them again afterwards?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All the software installed in macOS (along with the ones you mentioned) remain intact between OS upgrades.

However, it is advisable to keep an up-to-date backup before performing the upgrade.

Comment: I used Time Machine about 30 minutes ago.

Comment: If you are sure you have a working backup, you can go ahead and perform the upgrade.

Comment: @WayneSmallman You may also wish to refer to this answer:  https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/332616/279727

Comment: I've completed the update without problems. I've also checked with the web applications, which are also working.